# Solving $\int_0^1\frac{\log^4(1-x^2)}{1+x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

This question is similar to my [last question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4785630/solving-int-01-log21-x-log21xdx.).
It's also from the same book, Problem 1.8(iii).
$$I=\int_0^1\dfrac{\log^4(1-x^2)}{1+x}dx$$
[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5BPower%5Blog%5C%2840%291-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29%2C4%5D%2C1%2Bx%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C1%7D%5D) can't give the closed form, it is only giving a numerical expression.
According to the book $$I=\dfrac{16}{5}\log^52-16\log^32\zeta(2)+48\log^22\zeta(3)-54\log2\zeta(4)-24\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+72\zeta(5)$$
I tried taking substitutions like $y=1-x^2$. It didn't take me anywhere. Is there some way to solve this integral?

Comment: The bad joke is that Wolfram Alpha returns the antiderivative. No problem to eveluate it at $x=0$ but about $x=1$, I did not find any way

Comment: \begin{align}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 x\ln(1+x)}{1+x}dx=\frac{87}{16}\zeta(5)-3\zeta(2)\zeta(3)\end{align}
is more cool!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Complete solution.**

No harmonic sums, no Beta function are used.

The "obvious" part,
\begin{align}J&=\int_0^1\frac{\log^4(1-x^2)}{1+x}dx\\
&=2\int_0^1\frac{\log^4(1-x)}{1+x}dx+12\int_0^1\frac{\log^2(1-x)\log^2(1+x)}{1+x}dx+2\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\log^4(1+x)}{1+x}dx}_{=\frac{1}{5}\ln^5 2}-\\&
\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\log^4(\frac{1-x}{1+x})}{1+x}dx}_{u=\frac{1-x}{1+x}}\\
&=2\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\log^4(1-x)}{1+x}dx}_{=J_1}+12\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\log^2(1-x)\log^2(1+x)}{1+x}dx}_{=J_2}+\frac{2}{5}\ln^5 2-\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^4 u}{1+u}du}_{=J_3}\\
J_3&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4 u}{1-u}du-\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{2u\ln^4 u}{1-u^2}du}_{z=u^2}=\left(1-\frac{1}{16}\right)\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4 u}{1-u}du=\boxed{\frac{45}{2}\zeta(5)}\\
J_1&\overset{u=1-x}=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^4 u}{1-\frac{u}{2}}du=24\text{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
\end{align}

The hardest part is to compute,
\begin{align}J_2=\int_0^1\frac{\log^2(1-x)\log^2(1+x)}{1+x}dx\end{align}

NB:I assume,
\begin{align}a\neq 0,\left|a\right|\leq 1,n\geq 1,\text{integer},\int_0^1\frac{\ln^n x}{1-ax}dx=\frac{(-1)^nn!}{a}\text{Li}_{n+1}(a)\end{align}

**First addendum.**
\begin{align}K_n&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^n (1+x)}{x}dx\\
&\overset{u=\frac{1}{1+x}}=(-1)^n\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1\frac{\ln^n u}{u(1-u)}du=\frac{\left(\ln 2\right)^{n+1}}{1+n}+(-1)^n\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1\frac{\ln^n u}{1-u}du\\
&=\frac{\left(\ln 2\right)^{n+1}}{1+n}+(-1)^n\int_0^1\frac{\ln^n u}{1-u}du-(-1)^n\underbrace{\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\ln^n u}{1-u}du}_{z=2u}\\
\end{align}

For $n\geq 1$, integer,
\begin{align}A_n&=\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{\ln^n x}{1-x}dx\\
&\overset{z=2x}=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^n\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)}{1-\frac{z}{2}}dz=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\frac{\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k(\ln 2)^k(\ln z)^{n-k}}{1-\frac{z}{2}}dz\\
&=(-1)^n(\ln 2)^{n+1}+(-1)^n\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}(n-k)!(\ln 2)^k\text{Li}_{n+1-k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}_{l=n-k}\\&=\boxed{(-1)^n(\ln 2)^{n+1}+(-1)^n\sum_{l=1}^n\binom{n}{l}l!(\ln 2)^{n-l}\text{Li}_{l+1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}\\
K_n&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^n (1+x)}{x}dx\\
&\overset{u=\frac{1}{1+x}}=(-1)^n\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1\frac{\ln^n u}{u(1-u)}du=\frac{\left(\ln 2\right)^{n+1}}{1+n}+(-1)^n\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1\frac{\ln^n u}{1-u}du\\
&=\frac{\left(\ln 2\right)^{n+1}}{1+n}+(-1)^n\int_0^1\frac{\ln^n u}{1-u}du-(-1)^n\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\ln^n u}{1-u}du\\
&=\frac{\left(\ln 2\right)^{n+1}}{1+n}+n!\zeta(n+1)-(-1)^nA_n\\&=\boxed{\frac{-n\left(\ln 2\right)^{n+1}}{1+n}+n!\zeta(n+1)-\sum_{l=1}^n\binom{n}{l}l!(\ln 2)^{n-l}\text{Li}_{l+1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}
\end{align}
\begin{align}J_2&\overset{u=\frac{1-x}{1+x}}=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2\left(\frac{2}{1+u}\right)\left(\ln^2\left(\frac{2}{1+u}\right)+\ln^2 u+2\ln\left(\frac{2}{1+u}\right)\ln u\right)}{1+u}du\\
&=\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^4\left(\frac{2}{1+u}\right)}{1+u}du}_{z=\frac{1-u}{1+u}}-2\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 (1+u)\ln u}{1+u}du}_{\text{IBP}}+\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 (1+u)\ln^2 u}{1+u}du}_{=J_4}+6\times\\&\ln 2\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 (1+u)\ln u}{1+u}du}_{\text{IBP}}-
2\ln 2\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+u)\ln^2 u}{1+u}du}_{=J_5}-6\ln^2 2\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln (1+u)\ln u}{1+u}du}_{\text{IBP}}+\\&\ln^2 2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 u}{1+u}du+2\ln^3 2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln u}{1+u}du\\
&=\frac{\ln^5 2}{5}+\frac{K_4}{2}+J_4-2K_3\ln 2-2J_5\ln 2+3K_2\ln^2 2+\frac{3\zeta(3)\ln^2 2}{2}-\frac{\pi^2\ln^3 2}{6}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
J_5&=-\frac{1}{3}\left(\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3\left(\frac{u}{1+u}\right)}{1+u}du}_{z=\frac{u}{1+u}}-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3 u}{1+u}du+\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1+u)}{1+u}du-3\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1+u)\ln u}{1+u}du}_{\text{IBP}}\right)\\
&=-\frac{A_3}{3}-\frac{7\pi^4}{360}-\frac{\ln^4 2}{12}-\frac{K_3}{3}
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}J_2=3K_2\ln^2 2-\frac{4K_3\ln 2}{3}+\frac{K_4}{2}+\frac{2A_3\ln 2}{3}+\frac{11\ln^5 2}{30}-\frac{\pi^2\ln^3 2}{6}+\frac{3\zeta(3)\ln^2 2}{2}+\frac{7\pi^4\ln 2}{180}+J_4\end{align}
Since,
\begin{align}K_2&=-\frac{2\ln^3 2}{3}+2\zeta(3)-2\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\ln 2-2\text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{\zeta(3)}{4}\\
A_3&=-\ln^4 2-3\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\ln^2 2-6\text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\ln 2-6\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
&=-\frac{\ln^4 2}{2}+\frac{\pi^2\ln^2 2}{4}-\frac{21\zeta(3)\ln 2}{4}-6\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
K_3&=-\frac{\ln^4 2}{4}+\frac{\pi^2\ln^2 2}{4}-\frac{21\zeta(3)\ln 2}{4}+\frac{\pi^4}{15}-6\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
K_4&=-\frac{4\ln^5 2}{5}+\frac{2\pi^2\ln^3 2}{3}-\frac{21\zeta(3)\ln^2 2}{2}-24\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\ln 2+24\zeta(5)-24\text{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)
\end{align}
then,
\begin{align}J_2=-\frac{\ln^5 2}{30}+\frac{\zeta(3)\ln^2 2}{2}-\frac{\pi^4\ln 2}{20}-8\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\ln 2+12\zeta(5)-12\text{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+J_4\end{align}
I assume,
\begin{align}\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)&=\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\frac{\ln^2 2}{2},\text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{7\zeta(3)}{8}+\frac{\ln^3 2}{6}-\frac{\pi^2 \ln 2}{12}\\
\end{align}

To terminate the computation i have to compute,
\begin{align}J_4=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1+x)\ln^2 x}{1+x}dx\overset{?}=\end{align}

**To be continued...**

**Second addendum.**

$m\geq 0, n\geq 0$, integers
\begin{align}W_{m,n}&=\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{\ln^m(1-x)\ln^nx}{1-x}dx\end{align}
Since,
\begin{align}W_{2,2}&\overset{\text{IBP}}=-\frac{1}{3}\Big[\ln^3(1-x)\ln^2 x\Big]_0^{\frac{1}{2}}+\frac{2}{3}\underbrace{\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{\ln^3(1-x)\ln x}{x}dx}_{u=1-x}\\
&=\frac{\ln^5 2}{3}+\frac{2}{3}\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-u)\ln^3 u}{1-u}du}_{=J_6}-\frac{2}{3}W_{1,3}\\
W_{3,1}&\overset{\text{IBP}}=-\frac{1}{4}\Big[\ln^4(1-x)\ln  x\Big]_0^{\frac{1}{2}}+\frac{1}{4}\underbrace{\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{\ln^4(1-x)}{x}dx}_{u=1-x}\\
&=\frac{\ln^5 2}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^4 u}{1-u}du-\frac{1}{4}A_4=\frac{\ln^5 2}{4}+6\zeta(5)-\frac{1}{4}A_4\\
\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\ln^4\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)}{1-x}dx&=A_4-4W_{1,3}+6W_{2,2}-4W_{3,1}+\underbrace{W_{4,0}}_{=\frac{\ln^5 2}{5}}\\
&=2A_4+\frac{6\ln^5 2}{5}-24\zeta(5)-8W_{1,3}+4J_6\\
J_4&\overset{u=\frac{x}{1+x}}=\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\ln^2(1-u)\ln^2\left(\frac{u}{1-u}\right)}{1-u}du=W_{2,2}-2W_{3,1}+W_{4,0}\\
&=\frac{A_4}{2}+\frac{\ln^5 2}{30}-12\zeta(5)-\frac{2W_{1,3}}{3}+\frac{2J_6}{3}
\end{align}
then,
\begin{align}-\frac{1}{8}\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\ln^4\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)}{1-x}dx+\frac{3}{2}J_4&=\frac{A_4}{2}-\frac{\ln^5 2}{10}-15\zeta(5)+\frac{J_6}{2}\\
J_4&=\frac{A_4}{3}-\frac{\ln^5 2}{15}-10\zeta(5)+\frac{1}{12}\underbrace{\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\ln^4\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)}{1-x}dx}_{u=\frac{x}{1-x}}+\frac{J_6}{3}\\
&=\frac{A_4}{3}-\frac{\ln^5 2}{15}-\frac{65\zeta(5)}{8}+\frac{J_6}{3}\\
\end{align}
Since,
\begin{align}A_4=\ln^5 2-\frac{2\pi^2\ln^3 2}{3}+\frac{21\zeta(3)\ln^2 2}{2}+24\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\ln 2+24\text{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\end{align}
then,
\begin{align}J_4&=\frac{4\ln^5 2}{15}-\frac{2\pi^2\ln^3 2}{9}+\frac{7\zeta(3)\ln^2 2}{2}+8\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\ln 2-\frac{65\zeta(5)}{8}+8\text{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{J_6}{3}\end{align}
To terminate the computation, i have to compute $\displaystyle J_6=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)\ln^3 x}{1-x}dx$.

The use of Beta function, harmonic sums are possible ways, but there is an alternative.

**To be continued...**

**Epilogue.**

\begin{align}J_6&\overset{\text{IBP}}=\left[\ln(1-x)\left(\int_0^x\frac{\ln^3 t}{1-t}dt-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3 t}{1-t}dt\right)\right]_0^1+\\&\int_0^1\int_0^1\left(\frac{x\ln^3(tx)}{(1-x)(1-tx)}- \frac{\ln^3 t}{(1-x)(1-t)}\right)dtdx\\
&=\int_0^1\int_0^1\left(\frac{\ln^3 x+3\ln^2x\ln t+3\ln x\ln^2 t}{(1-x)(1-t)}-\frac{\ln^3(tx)}{(1-t)(1-tx)}\right)dtdx\\
&\overset{\text{Fubini}}=-2\pi^2\zeta(3)+\int_0^1\int_0^1\left(\frac{\ln^3 x}{(1-x)(1-t)}-\frac{\ln^3(tx)}{(1-t)(1-tx)}\right)dtdx\\
&=-2\pi^2\zeta(3)+\int_0^1\left(\frac{1}{1-t}\left(\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 x}{1-x}dx\right)-\frac{1}{t(1-t)}\left(\int_0^t\frac{\ln^3 u}{1-u}du\right)\right)dt\\
&=-2\pi^2\zeta(3)+\int_0^1\left(\frac{1}{1-t}\left(\int_t^1 \frac{\ln^3 x}{1-x}dx\right)-\frac{1}{t}\left(\int_0^t\frac{\ln^3 u}{1-u}du\right)\right)dt\\
&\overset{\text{IBP}}=-2\pi^2\zeta(3)-J_6+\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4 t}{1-t}dt}_{=24\zeta(5)}\\
J_6&=\boxed{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-t)\ln^3 t}{1-t}dt=12\zeta(5)-\pi^2\zeta(3)}\\
J_4&=\\&\boxed{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1+t)\ln^2 t}{1+t}dt=\frac{4\ln^5 2}{15}-\frac{2\pi^2\ln^3 2}{9}+\frac{7\zeta(3)\ln^2 2}{2}+8\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\ln 2-\frac{\pi^2\zeta(3)}{3}-\frac{33\zeta(5)}{8}+8\text{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}\\
J_2&=\\&\boxed{\int_0^1\!\frac{\ln^2(1-t)\!\ln^2(1+t)}{1+t}\!\!dt\!=\frac{7\ln^5 2}{30}\!-\!\frac{2\pi^2\ln^3 2}{9}+4\zeta(3)\ln^2 2-\frac{\pi^4\ln 2}{20}-\frac{\pi^2\zeta(3)}{3}+\frac{63\zeta(5)}{8}-4\text{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}\\
J&=\\&\boxed{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^4(1-t^2)}{1+t}dt=\frac{16\ln^5 2}{5}-\frac{8\pi^2\ln^3 2}{3}+48\zeta(3)\ln^2 2-\frac{3\pi^4\ln 2}{5}-4\pi^2\zeta(3)+72\zeta(5)}
\end{align}
**Proof completed.**

**Bonus.**
\begin{align}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)\ln^3 x}{1+x}dx&=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^4(1+x)}{1+x}dx-\underbrace{\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^4\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)}{1+x}dx}_{u=\frac{x}{1+x}}+\frac{3}{2}J_4+\\&\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4 x}{1+x}dx-\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3(1+x)\ln x}{1+x}dx}_{\text{IBP}}\\
&=\frac{\ln^5 2}{20}-\frac{A_4}{4}+\frac{3}{2}J_4+\frac{45\zeta(5)}{8}+\frac{K_4}{4}=\boxed{\frac{87\zeta(5)}{16}-\frac{\pi^2\zeta(3)}{2}}
\end{align}

Comment: It doesn't help a lot as the integral in the OP arose in the calculation of the integral $J_2$ in your answer. So, it goes in a circle.

Comment: @Souparna: I hope to prove you soon you are wrong ;)

Comment: I'd be kinda glad to be proved wrong.

Comment: @Souparna: The best i can do for now is to link this integral to this one,$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 x\ln(1+x)}{1+x}dx$ or to this one, $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 x\ln(1-x)}{1+x}dx$, none i can compute for now.

Comment: Consider :
$$J\left(m,n\right)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^m\left(s\right)\ln^n\left(1+s\right)}{1+s}ds$$
@FDP Just another relation, might help or maybe not :
$$4J\left(1,3\right)-3J\left(2,2\right)=-\frac{93}{8}\cdot \zeta\left(5\right)+6\cdot\zeta\left(2\right)\zeta\left(3\right)$$

Comment: @Black Emperor: When you develop $\displaystyle \int_0^1\frac{\ln^4\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)}{1+x}dx$, you get a rational linear combination of $\displaystyle U_{m,n}= \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^m(1+x)\ln^n x}{1+x}$. If only one hasn't an "obvious" computation it's ok,  but, here, two are difficult to evaluate $U_{1,3}$ and $U_{2,2}$.

Comment: @Black Emperor: Your relation is far from being obvious.

Answer (score 3):

**Too long for a comment**

One very elegant way is to exploit *The Master Theorem of Series* given in **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series (2019)**. So, we have that

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log^4(1-x^2)}{1+x} \textrm{d}x$$
$$\small =\frac{1}{4}\lim_{n\to -1/2 }\frac{H_n^5+10H_n^3 H_n^{(2)}+15 H_n (H_n^{(2)})^2+20 H_n^2 H_n^{(3)}+20 H_n^{(2)} H_n^{(3)}+30 H_n H_n^{(4)}+24 H_n^{(5)}}{5 n},$$

**and done**. One would usually like to use the Polygamma function notation (here one may observe the special cases with the argument $1/2$ are well-known).

Who cares to learn to use *The Master Theorem of Series* may find examples with its use and power both in **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series (2019)** and **More (Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series (2023)**.

**End of story**

Comment: I don't really get how we can derive this or further simplify it. Can you please elaborate a little?

Comment: @Souparna You may check a simpler similar case presented in the sequel, on page $630$.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully an Answer in progress If I can work on it but just consider it as a long comment right now.

---

$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^4\left(1-x^{2}\right)}{1+x}dx$$

Rewrite:
$$\ln\left(1-x^{2}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)+2\ln\left(1+x\right)$$
and expand.

Consider :
$$I(m,n)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)^{m}\ln\left(1+x\right)^{n}}{1+x}dx$$

Then,
$$I=I\left(4,0\right)+16I\left(0,4\right)+24I\left(2,2\right)+32I\left(1,3\right)+8I\left(3,1\right)$$

By Wolfram:
$$16I(0,4)=\frac{16}{5}\ln^5\left(2\right)$$

Which is also a term directly present in the answer given in OP.

This makes me think that this could be the correct approach.

Also by Wolfram,

$$I(4,0)=\frac{45}{2}\zeta(5)$$

Comment: Hint: Compute $(a+b)^4+(a-b)^4$ (result contains 3 terms, not 5)

Comment: Actually, the difficult part is to compute, $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^4(1-x)}{1+x}dx,\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1-x)\ln^2(1+x)}{1+x}dx$ all the remaining is "obvious" as far as i can see.

Comment: $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^4(1-x)}{1+x}dx$ is "obvious" too, if you know that the expression for it contains $\displaystyle \text{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$