Evaluate this integration : $\Omega = \int^1_0 \frac{\ln^3(1-x^2)}{1+x}dx$
Evaluate this integration :
$$\Omega = \int^1_0 \frac{\ln^3(1-x^2)}{1+x}dx$$
My attempt :
\begin{align*}
\Omega & =\int^1_0 \frac{\ln^3(1-x^2)}{1+x}dx\overset{t=\frac{1-x}{1+x}}{=}\int^1_0\frac{\ln^3\left({\frac{4t}{(t+1)^2}}\right)}{t+1}dt \\ &= \underbrace{\int^1_0\frac{\ln^3(4t)}{t+1}dt}_{I_1} -8\underbrace{\int^1_0\frac{\ln^3(1+t)}{1+t}dt}_{I_2} -6\underbrace{\int^1_0 \frac{\ln^2(4t)\ln(t+1)}{t+1}dt}_{I_3}+12\underbrace{\int^1_0\frac{\ln(4t)\ln(1+t)}{t+1}dt}_{I_4}
\end{align*}
$$I_2 = \int^1_0\frac{\ln^3(1+t)}{1+t}dt = \frac{1}{4}\ln^4(2)$$
\begin{align*}
I_1 = \int^1_0\frac{\ln^3(4t)}{t+1}dt &= \ln^3(4)\int^1_0\frac{1}{t+1}dt +\int^1_0\frac{\ln^3(t)}{t+1}dt + 3\ln^2(4)\int^1_0\frac{\ln(t)}{t+1}dt+3\ln(4)\int^1_0\frac{\ln^2(t)}{t+1}dt \\ &= \ln^3(4)\ln(2) -\frac{7}{120}\pi^4-\frac{\ln^2(4)}{4}\pi^2+\frac{9}{2}\zeta(3)\ln(4)\\&= 8\ln^4(2)-\frac{7}{120}\pi^4-\pi^2\ln^2(2)+9\zeta(3)\ln(2)
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
I_3 = \int^1_0 \frac{\ln^2(4t)\ln(t+1)}{t+1}dt &= \ln^2(4)\int^1_0\frac{\ln(t+1)}{t+1}dt+\int^1_0 \frac{\ln^2(t)\ln(t+1)}{t+1}dt+2\ln(4)\int^1_0 \frac{\ln(t)\ln(t+1)}{t+1}dt\\ &= 2\ln^4(2) + \int^1_0 \frac{\ln^2(t)\ln(t+1)}{t+1}dt +2\ln(4)\int^1_0 \frac{\ln(t)\ln(t+1)}{t+1}dt
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
I_4 &= \int^1_0\frac{\ln(4t)\ln(1+t)}{t+1}dt = \ln(4)\int^1_0 \frac{\ln(1+t)}{1+t}dt+\int^1_0\frac{\ln(1+t)\ln(t)}{1+t}dt\\&= \ln^3(2) +\int^1_0\frac{\ln(1+t)\ln(t)}{1+t}dt 
\end{align*}
My question : Is there a way to evaluate these two integrals?
$$\int^1_0 \frac{\ln(t)\ln(1+t)}{1+t}dt $$
$$\int^1_0 \frac{\ln^2(t)\ln(1+t)}{1+t}dt$$

This would be much better with some explanation with each step, instead of a wall of symbols.

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log(t)\log(1+t)}{1+t},dt=-\frac18 \zeta(3)$$

@MarkViola What about the second integral?

The integral evaluates to $$\int^1_0 \frac{\ln^3(1-x^2)}{1+x}dx
=12\zeta(3)\ln2-\frac{3\pi^4}{40}-\pi^2\ln^2 2+2\ln^4 2
$$

A generalization to your main integral can be found in this link https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4790989/432085.  About your sub integrals, there is a generalization if the power of the ln(x) is odd.

@AliShadhar Nice thank's

To solve the original integral, start with substitution $x=\sqrt u$
$$I=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1-x^2)}{1+x}dx=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1-x)}{2\sqrt x(1+\sqrt x)}dx=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1-x)}{1-x}\frac{1-\sqrt x}{2\sqrt x}dx$$
Now use integration by parts
$$u=\frac{x^{-1/2}-1}{2}, \space dv=\frac{\ln^3(1-x)}{1-x}dx$$
$$du=-\frac{x^{-3/2}}{4},\space v=-\frac{1}{4}\ln^4(1-x)$$
$$I=-\frac{1}{16}\int_0^1x^{-3/2}\ln^4(1-x)dx=-\frac{1}{16}\lim_{(x,y)→(-1/2,1)}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)^4B(x,y)$$
Calculating the 4th derivative of the beta function by hand is tedious but doable. Use
$$(\Gamma(x))'=\Gamma(x)\psi_0(x)$$
$$(\psi_n(x))'=\psi_{n+1}(x)$$
where $\Gamma(x)$ is the gamma function and $\psi_n(x)$ is the polygamma function

$$-\frac{1}{16}\lim_{(x,y)→(-1/2,1)}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)^4B(x,y)=\frac{\sqrt\pi}8\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)^4,\bigg|_{y=0}e^{\ln\Gamma(1+y)-\ln\Gamma \big(\frac12+y\big)}$$
and then we can use (or evaluate) $\psi^{(k)}(x)=\left(\frac d{dx}\right)^{k+1}\ln\Gamma(x)$ representations for $,x=1,,\frac12$
$$\psi^{(k)}(1)=(-1)^{k+1}k!\zeta(k+1);,,\psi^{(k)}(1/2)=(-1)^{k+1}k!(2^{k+1}-1)\zeta(k+1)$$
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygammaFunction.html

\begin{align}J&=\frac{\ln(1+x)\ln^2x}{1+x}dx=\frac{1}{3}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x}{1+x}dx-\frac{1}{3}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3\left(1+x\right)}{1+x}dx+\\&\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2\left(1+x\right)\ln x}{1+x}dx}_{\text{IBP}}-\frac{1}{3}\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)}{1+x}dx}_{u=\frac{x}{1+x}}\\
&=-\frac{7\zeta(4)}{4}-\frac{\ln^42}{12}-\frac{1}{3}\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1+x)}{x}dx}_{u=\frac{1}{1+x}}-\frac13\int_0^{\frac12}\frac{\ln^3u}{1-u}du\\
&=-\frac{7\zeta(4)}{4}-\frac{\ln^42}{12}+\frac{1}{3}\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1\frac{\ln^3u}{u(1-u)}du-\frac13\int_0^{\frac12}\frac{\ln^3u}{1-u}du\\
&=-\frac{7\zeta(4)}{4}-\frac{\ln^42}{6}+\frac{1}{3}\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1\frac{\ln^3u}{1-u}du-\frac13\int_0^{\frac12}\frac{\ln^3u}{1-u}du\\
&=-\frac{15\zeta(4)}{4}-\frac{\ln^42}{6}-\frac23\underbrace{\int_0^{\frac12}\frac{\ln^3u}{1-u}du}_{z=\frac z 2}\\
&=-\frac{15\zeta(4)}{4}-\frac{\ln^42}{6}-\frac{1}{3}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3\left(\frac z2\right)}{1-\frac z2}dz\\
&=-\frac{15\zeta(4)}{4}-\frac{\ln^42}{6}-\frac13\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3z}{1-\frac z2}dz+\frac13\int_0^1\frac{\ln^32}{1-\frac z2}dz-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^22\ln z}{1-\frac z2}dz+\\&\int_0^1\frac{\ln 2\ln^2 z}{1-\frac z2}dz\\
&=-\frac{15\zeta(4)}{4}+\frac{\ln^42}{2}+4\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\left(\ln^2 2-\frac{\pi^2}{6}\right)\ln^2 2+\\&\left(\frac{7\zeta(3)}{2}+\frac{2}{3}\ln^3 2-\frac{\pi^2\ln 2}{3}\right)\ln 2\\
&=\boxed{4\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{\pi^4}{24}+\frac{7\zeta(3)\ln 2}{2}-\frac{\pi^2\ln^22}6+\frac{\ln^42}6}
\end{align}
NB:
Same method is applicable to the integral $\displaystyle \int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)\ln x}{1+x}dx$
